# Trying to stack multiple layouts into activity in android app, keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview, android-framelayout

I have decided to try making a separate layout for a boat object (imageView) that I am putting over the background image.

The reason for this, is that I want to be able to attach a person object to the boat object when the person is clicked on.

That way, when the boat object is clicked, the person object moves with it.  I have tried writing the code for adding layouts programmatically according to what I was able to find online, but the app keeps crashing.

Here is the main activity:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    FrameLayout boatlayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    Boat boatobject = (Boat)findViewById(R.id.boatimageView);   
    //Person personobject = (Person)findViewById(R.id.personView1);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    boatlayout.addView(boatobject, params);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);           
    this.addContentView(boatlayout,parentParams);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

This is the main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <com.cannibal_photographer.Person
            android:id="@+id/personView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/greensquare" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the boatlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/framelayoutView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.cannibal_photographer.Boat
    android:id="@+id/boatimageView"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:src="@drawable/boat" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And finally here is the stack trace:

```
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cannibal_photographer/com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3338)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3186)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-17 08:50:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(2283):     ... 11 more
10-17 08:53:04.651: E/Trace(2381): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-17 08:53:05.611: D/dalvikvm(2381): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 6% free 2556K/2712K, paused 96ms, total 98ms
10-17 08:53:05.631: I/dalvikvm-heap(2381): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.245MB for 2764816-byte allocation
10-17 08:53:05.681: D/dalvikvm(2381): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 5254K/5416K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
10-17 08:53:05.731: D/dalvikvm(2381): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 5264K/5416K, paused 4ms+14ms, total 50ms
10-17 08:53:05.731: D/AndroidRuntime(2381): Shutting down VM
10-17 08:53:05.731: W/dalvikvm(2381): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cannibal_photographer/com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3338)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3186)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-17 08:53:05.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2381):     ... 11 more
```

**UPDATE:**

Carnal was right, I found this documentation which helped solved the problem:

http://khajanpndey.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-layoutinflater-tutorial.html

Comment: Why are you trying to access the `Boat` layout in your activity though its defined in another layout?

Comment: You are calling `findViewById(R.id.boatimageView)`. Is `boatimageView` is present in your `activity_main.xml` ??? And what is this `android:id="@layout/activity_main"`? Why dont try a simple Hello World app before performing some runtime stacking ?

Comment: Have you added `Boat` class in your project ?

Comment: boatimageView is contained in the boatlayout.xml, not the activity_main.xml.  I was trying to figure out a way to access the boat layout as well.  The activit_main contains the background image information and the personView, although I'm not using the person part yet.

Comment: You can not access Boat layout from main activity as you have set the activity_main layout in it. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Boat boatobject = (Boat)findViewById(R.id.boatimageView);
```

will give you `null` on `boatobject` since you are looking for `R.id.boatimageView` in your layout `activity_main` => `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Since you have two different layout files, you need to use `LayoutInflater` in order to inflate the second layout `boatlayout.xml`. The from this `View` that you will obtain by using `LayoutInflater` you can get your `Boat` object with:

```
Boat boatobject = (Boat) viewFromSecondXml.findViewById(R.id.boatimageView);
```

Comment: I think this is the problem, I'm reading up on LayoutInflater right now.  Once I make a little headway with it, I'll confirm whether or not this solved it.

Comment: This is what I needed, researching a little further after your suggestion, I found this documentation which solved my problem:

http://khajanpndey.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-layoutinflater-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

As you are inflating the `acitivity_main` layout in your `MainActivity` then you are supposed to initialize the `Person` view not `Boat` view in your `onCreate()`. It will always give you Nullpointer exception because the `Boat` view is not defined in `activity_main` layout.

So besides using `Boat` try to access `Person` View as below:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    FrameLayout boatlayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    Person personobject = (Person)findViewById(R.id.personView1);
```